# Cloudformation Unresolved resource dependencies

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am attempting to build my first larger Cloudformation template; however, I keep running into issues with the Image selection process as it does not like my current configuration.

I am trying to have a user select a Windows OS version, which would then have the CFN Template select the AMI that matches this Windows version.

```
yaml    
Mappings: 
  ImageMapping: 
    WindowsImage: 
      Windows2008R2: ami-0d8a5c68b4550ced5
      Windows2012: ami-0196cda9251876643
      Windows2012R2: ami-0196cda9251876643
      Windows2016: ami-04ad37d2932b886c0
      Windows2019: ami-04ad37d2932b886c0
Parameters:
  ImageIdParameters: 
        AllowedValues: 
          - Windows2019
          - Windows2016
          - Windows2012R2
          - Windows2012
          - Windows2008R2
        Default: Windows2019
        Description: "Enter Windows OS Version. Default Windows 2019"
        Type: String
Rescources:
    EC2Instance:
        Properties:
          ImageId: !FindInMap [ImageMapping, !Ref "WindowsImage", !Ref ImageIdParameters]
```

Template contains errors.: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [WindowsImage] in the Resources block of the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be simply `WindowsImage`, not `!Ref "WindowsImage"`:

```
!FindInMap [ImageMapping, WindowsImage, !Ref ImageIdParameters]
```

Or:

```
ImageId: !FindInMap
  - ImageMapping
  - WindowsImage
  - !Ref ImageIdParameters
```